# Stepper motor release L298N

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper, l298n

I'm Driving a stepper using a L298N driver and an arduino mega. I want to release the stepper after the movement so it can swing freely, because it gets hot, and it doesn't need to hold position.

Anyone know how to do it? I'm using just the basic stepper library.

Thank you.

Comment: Set Enable A; Enable B to LOW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should set Enable (A and B) pins on L298 to LOW, effectively turning off the driver.